# Replace next occurrence of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

*I am playing around, trying to make something that I might use in the future for an project that I have idea for.
However, I can't seem to make it work properly. I am sure that this is not the best way to do it, but it's the only way I was able to think of. Hence it may be why I can't make it work either.*

**Problem:**
Well the problem is that the function does not replace the next word occurrence in a string of multiple existing words. Instead it goes back to the same word that is first in a string. I tried some `RegExp` solutions from here, but failed to make it work.

**What is it suppoused to do?** Just to loop trough each word and highlight it for a moment. It should use that `generateTime` array to set different looping time for each word. Later on that will be an `JSON` object mostlikely.

[CodePen Demo / Example](http://codepen.io/dvLden/pen/ByGKbg)

Here's the JS code only:

```js
var // ->
textElement     = $( '.text' ),
contentReplace  = textElement.text().replace( /[^\w ]/g, '' ).split( /\s+/ ),
generateTime    = [],
inc             = 0,
interval        = false;

// Generate random time
for ( var i = 0; i <= contentReplace.length; i++ ) {
    generateTime.push( Math.random() * (1 - 0.1) + 0.1 );
}

// Interval for looping trough words
var ticker = setInterval(function () {
    if ( inc == ( generateTime.length - 2 ) ) {
        clearTimeout( ticker );
    }

    if ( ! interval ) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            textElement
                .html( textElement.text().replace(contentReplace[inc], '<span>' + contentReplace[inc] + '</span>') );

            inc++;
            interval = false;
        }, generateTime[inc] * 1000);    
    }

    interval = true;
}, 500);
```

If anyone could help me to resolve this problem I'm having

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your code is _supposed_ to do. Highlight each word, one at a time, no matter what the word is? Or only highlight the first occurrence of each word?

Comment: @blex... Well that would be pretty much it. Highlighting each word one at a time using random  `generateTime` which would be an `jsonObject` later on.

Comment: It does exactly that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep track of the last matched index. Try this:

```js
var // ->
textElement     = $( '.text' ),
contentReplace  = textElement.text().replace( /[^\w ]/g, '' ).split( /\s+/ ),
generateTime    = [],
inc             = 0,
interval        = false;
lastIndex       = 0;

// Generate random time
for ( var i = 0; i <= contentReplace.length; i++ ) {
  generateTime.push( Math.random() * (1 - 0.1) + 0.1 );
}

// Interval for looping trough words
var ticker = setInterval(function () {
  if ( inc == ( generateTime.length - 2 ) ) {
    clearTimeout( ticker );
  }
  
  if ( ! interval ) {
   setTimeout(function () {
      var text = textElement.text();
      textElement
       .html( text.substr( 0, lastIndex ) + text.substr( lastIndex, text.length ).replace( contentReplace[inc], function ( match, index ) {
            lastIndex = lastIndex + index + match.length;
            return '<span>' + contentReplace[inc] + '</span>'
         }));

      inc++;
      interval = false;
    }, generateTime[inc] * 1000);  
  }
  
  interval = true;
}, 500);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  background-color: #c22;
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">Lets try to make it work. Try, then try again and once again - try.</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if that's the only solution to it. But for now it is the only given one so I'll stick with it. +1

Comment: @dvLden definitely not the only solution. Just the first one that came to mind.